# Solve the equation $\sqrt[2021]{\frac{2x+2021}{x+4042}}+\sqrt[2021]{\frac{x+4042}{2x+2021}}=\cos\frac{(2021+x)\pi}{47}+\cos\frac{(2021-x)\pi}{43}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$\sqrt[2021]{\dfrac{2x+2021}{x+4042}}+\sqrt[2021]{\dfrac{x+4042}{2x+2021}}=\cos\dfrac{(2021+x)\pi}{47}+\cos\dfrac{(2021-x)\pi}{43}$$

I'd say my observations of the problem are superficial and don't lead to anything that will help us solve it.

Anyway, we can note that $$\sqrt[2021]{\dfrac{2x+2021}{x+4042}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[2021]{\dfrac{x+4042}{2x+2021}}},$$ so if we put $\sqrt[2021]{\dfrac{2x+2021}{x+4042}}=a\ne0,$ the LHS becomes $$a+\dfrac{1}{a}$$ Using the identity $$\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=-2\sin\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\dfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2},$$ the RHS becomes $$-2\sin\dfrac{43\pi(2021+x)+47\pi(2021-x)}{4042}\sin\dfrac{43\pi(2021+x)-47\pi(2021-x)}{4042}$$

Comment: Hint: |LHS| $\ge 2$ , |RHS| $\le 2$.

Comment: I think the only possible solution is x=2021

Comment: $$
\cos\dfrac{(2021+x)\pi}{47}+\cos\dfrac{(2021-x)\pi}{43} = - \cos\dfrac{\pi x}{47} -  \cos\dfrac{\pi x}{43}. 
$$